# How to use stereo_image_proc without camera_info topics?

Tags: ros-humble, camera-info, stereo-camera, disparity

I'm working with 2 csi cameras in a jetson nano with ROS2 humble and I want to do a disparity image. What I'm trying to use is stereo_image_proc disparity node, but it requires to have the camera_info topics for both of the cameras. The camera is a imx219-83 and I haven't found a driver that allows me to have a camera_info topic. Is it possible to obtain this topic ? If not, is there something that could be helpful for this situations?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This tutorial](https://jeffzzq.medium.com/ros2-image-pipeline-tutorial-3b18903e7329) does exactly what you want, I think. They are also creating a disparity map with stereo_image_proc.

There you will calibrate your cameras and use the opencv_cam driver to read your devices. When reading you cameras with opencv_cam you can provide a calibration file (.yaml) that you created with the calibration, and open_cv cam will publish your image_raw and camera_info topic.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to tell that I'm working with dockers from dustynv (nvidia) , and I don't know why I cannot build correctly open_cv_cam. And I'm not so sure if that package works with csi cameras, do you know ?

Comment: @ThiagoBlanco CSI cameras should work to. As long as they appear when running `ls /dev/video*` you can use them for the opencv_cam package.
Do you get an error message when building opencv_cam ?

Comment: It wasn't compiling, but I hardcode it and it finally compiled. I didn't have time to try the library but I think it should work.

Thanks!

Comment: @ThiagoBlanco No problem, glad I could help. Make sure you accept this answer so other people can find it more quickly.

Comment: Sorry that I bother again. I was working with a lidar and left away a bit the camera sensor.  I am trying to use the opencv_cam and I get green screen, do you know why this could be happening ?

Comment: @ThiagoBlanco I think you need to provide more information. Maybe set up a new post, if the error persists.